# What's the quickest way to remove an element from a Map by value in Java?

Tags: java, performance, collections

What's the quickest way to remove an element from a Map by value in Java?

Currently I'm using:

```
    DomainObj valueToRemove = new DomainObj();
    String removalKey = null;

    for (Map.Entry<String, DomainObj> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (valueToRemove.equals(entry.getValue())) {
            removalKey = entry.getKey();
            break;
        }
    }

    if (removalKey != null) {
        map.remove(removalKey);
    }
```

Comment: I'm using Java's HashMap

Comment: why do you remove element in if statement? is it unsafe?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Without using a Bi-directional map ([commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/bidimap/package-summary.html) and [google collections](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) have them), you're stuck with iterating the Map

Comment: +1 recommending google collections BiMap.  It's faster, but comes with a memory overhead.

Comment: Or you can maintain two maps, which is what these maps do.

Answer (score 95):

The correct and fast one-liner would actually be:

```
while (map.values().remove(valueObject));
```

Kind of strange that most examples above assume the `valueObject` to be unique.

Comment: Which works in basic use cases, not with a provided predicate.

Answer (score 32):

Here's the one-line solution:

```
map.values().remove(valueToRemove);
```

That's probably faster than defining your own iterator, since the JDK collection code has been significantly optimized.

As others have mentioned, a bimap will have faster value removes, though it requires more memory and takes longer to populate. Also, a bimap only works when the values are unique, which may or may not be the case in your code.

Comment: But if valueToRemove is present twice in the map, won't this code only remove one value rather than both?

Comment: i think this operation is O(n)

Answer (score 19):

```
map.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

reference to  [How to filter "Null" values from HashMap<String, String>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863581/how-to-filter-null-values-from-hashmapstring-string),   we  can do following for java 8:

```
map.values().removeIf(valueToRemove::equals);
```

Comment: But the question does not ask about null values?

Comment: It is just an example, pay attention to Collections.singleton(null)

Answer (score 11):

If you don't have a reverse map, I'd go for an iterator.

```
DomainObj valueToRemove = new DomainObj();

for (
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, DomainObj>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
    iter.hasNext();
) {
    Map.Entry<String, DomainObj> entry = iter.next();
    if (valueToRemove.equals(entry.getValue())) {
        iter.remove();
        break; // if only want to remove first match.
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  The only other thing I would mention is that if you need to remove by value often, make sure a Map is the actual data structure you should be using for your scenario.

Answer (score 7):

You could always use the values collection, since any changes made to that collection will result in the change being reflected in the map. So if you were to call Map.values().remove(valueToRemove) that should work - though I'm not sure if you'll see performance better than what you have with that loop. One idea would be to extend or override the map class such that the backing collection then is always sorted by value - that would enable you to do a binary search on the value which may be faster.

Edit: This is essentially the same as Alcon's answer except I don't think his will work since the entrySet is still going to be ordered by key - in which case you can't call .remove() with the value.

This is also assuming that the value is supposed to be unique or that you would want to remove any duplicates from the Map as well.

Answer (score 6):

i would use this

```
 Map x = new HashMap();
x.put(1, "value1");
x.put(2, "value2");
x.put(3, "value3");
x.put(4, "value4");
x.put(5, "value5");
x.put(6, "value6");

x.values().remove("value4");
```

edit: 
   because objects are referenced by "pointer" not by value.

N

Comment: This works only if there is only one instance of "value4". If I have another entry with the value "value4", it wouldn't remove that entry.

Answer (score 4):

If you have no way to figure out the key from the DomainObj, then I don't see how you can improve on that.  There's no built in method to get the key from the value, so you *have* to iterate through the map.

If this is something you're doing all the time, you might maintain two maps (string->DomainObj and DomainObj->Key).

Comment: +1. You should find a way to store your value as some sort of key if you want to optimise. If you can't you don't have a choice : You have to iterate.

Answer (score 2):

Like most of the other posters have said, it's generally an O(N) operation because you're going to have to look through the whole list of hashtable values regardless. @tackline has the right solution for keeping the memory usage at O(1) (I gave him an up-vote for that).

Your other option is to sacrifice memory space for the sake of speed.  If your map is reasonably sized, you could store two maps in parallel.

If you have a Map then maintain a Map in parallel to it. When you insert/remove on one map, do it on the other also.  Granted this is uglier because you're wasting space and you'll have to make sure the "hashCode" method of DomainObj is written properly, but your removal time drops from O(N) to O(1) because you can lookup the key/object mapping in constant time either direction.

Not generally the best solution, but if your number one concern is speed, I think this is probably as fast as you're gonna get.

====================
Addendum: This essentially what @msaeed suggested just sans the third party library.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter usage of iterator is to use a values() iterator.

```
DomainObj valueToRemove = new DomainObj();
for (Iterator<DomainObj> it = map.values().iterator(); it.hasNext();)) {
        if (valueToRemove.equals(it.next())) {
                it.remove();
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We know this situation arise rarely but is extremely helpful. I'll prefer `BidiMap` from [org.apache.commons.collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html) .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will happen only once in the lifetime of your app.

So what I would do, is to delegate to another object the responsability to maintain a reference to the objects added to that map.

So the next time you need to remove it, you use that "reverse map" ...

```
 class MapHolder { 

     private Map<String, DomainObj> originalMap;
     private Map<DomainObj,String> reverseMap;

     public void remove( DomainObj value ) {
           if ( reverseMap.contains( value ) ) { 
                 originalMap.remove( reverseMap.get( value ) );
                 reverseMap.remove( value );
           }
     }
  }
```

This is much much faster than iterating.

Obviously you need to keep them synchronized. But it should not be that hard if you refector your code to have one object being responsible for the state of the map.

Remember that in OOP we have objects that have an state and behavior.  If your data is passing around variables all over the place, you are creating unnecessary dependencies between objects

Yes, It will take you some time to correct the code, but the time spent correcting it, will save you a lot of headaches in the future. Think about it.

Comment: This is a case of "reinventing the wheel", or in this case, the bi-directional Map. Google Collections supplies a thorough implementation.

Comment: requires that the value is unique which is no necessarily so.

Comment: @Steve: Well of course, a lot more for code should be added ( like implementing the Map interface to be able to synchronize put and get ) This is more like a "sketch" of the suggestion and not really a "ready to copy/paste" solution.  And yes, as an alternative there could be Google Collections, but the same principle applies, there should be one object responsible for that map and the bi-directional, and not passing references all around the code. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Thorbj... .. o rn Ravn Andersen. ( sorry I didin't found that o )  .. . You're correct. The value should have a associated a list of keys, the first one would be the one to be removed.... when no more keys are there in the list, the whole value is removed. I thought about that but, didn't posted because it would create a ugly code. That's why I said: "Obviously you need to keep..." but I agree with you.