# How to filter "Null" values from HashMap<String, String>?

Tags: java

Following map, having both key-value pair as String, Write a logic to filter all the null values from Map without using any external API's ?

Is there any other approach than traversing through whole map and filtering out the values (Traversing whole map and getting Entry Object and discarding those pair) ?

```
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

        map.put("1", "One");
        map.put("2", "Two");
        map.put("3", null);
        map.put("4", "Four");
        map.put("5", null);
        //Logic to filer values
        //Post filtering It should print only ( 1,2 & 4 pair )
```

Comment: No, there isn't. The traversal (it's just a loop) will either be in your code or in JDK code (streams, etc.), but there will need to be a loop.

Comment: If you don't want to allow `null` in the first place, you can subclass it and override `put` method.

Answer (score 111):

You can use the Java 8 method [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) for this purpose:

```
map.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

This removed all values that are null.

<kbd>[Online demo](https://ideone.com/KoYZby)</kbd>

This works by the fact that calling `.values()` for a HashMap returns a collection that delegated modifications back to the HashMap itself, meaning that our call for `removeIf()` actually changes the HashMap (this doesn't work on all java Map's)

Comment: Please explain how to convert the values() back into a hashmap in a single line approach, I see only values() but can't get it back?

Comment: The point is that you don't need to convert it back, for it to work

Comment: but what if I wish to keep the map format while filtering out the nulls? of course I could use the solutions below(and already did) but I thought you could provide an even more simple approach... to values.. filter.. and then back to map. thanks anyway tho.

Comment: @vasilevich `values()` is a view of the map's values. If you remove something from it, it removes the corresponding key/value pair from the map.

Comment: I have a map like this, above solution doesn't works `{first=null, self={href=/employee/1/employees}, next=null, last=null, prev=null}`

Comment: @PAA this only works with an hashmap, and probably not other maps. Check which implementation of map you are actually getting.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using pre-Java 8, you can use:

```
Collection<String> values = map.values();
while (values.remove(null)) {}
```

This works because `HashMap.values()` returns a view of the values, and:

> The collection [returned by `HashMap.values()`] supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations

An alternative way that might be faster, because you don't have to keep re-iterating the collection to find the first null element:

```
for (Iterator<?> it = map.values().iterator();
    it.hasNext();) {
  if (it.next() == null) {
    it.remove();
  }
}
```

Or you can do it without the explicit iteration:

```
values.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

Comment: Thanks Andy for solution.
I tried with your solution. It is working fine.

Answer (score 9):

that will work

```
Map<String, String> result = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
```

Comment: oh, excuse me. this only works for streams. We can convert to and from streams, let me update my answer.